# Get End Time by Adding Number of Minutes in Start Time Keeping in mind the working hours

Tags: mysql

I have database table in which I have daily working hours of office.
What I need is to get End Time by Adding Number of minutes in Start Time keeping in mind the office hours. The working hours are from 09:00 to 17:30

I will be thankful if some one could help me to write query in mysql so that I could calculate end time.

my Sample Table is

```
+------------------+------------------+  
| starttime        | endtime          |  
+------------------+------------------+  
| 2017-01-01 00:00 | 2017-01-01 00:00 |  
| 2017-01-02 09:00 | 2017-01-02 17:30 |  
| 2017-01-03 09:00 | 2017-01-03 17:30 |  
| 2017-01-04 09:00 | 2017-01-04 17:30 |  
| 2017-01-05 09:00 | 2017-01-05 17:30 |  
| 2017-01-06 09:00 | 2017-01-06 17:30 |  
| 2017-01-07 09:00 | 2017-01-07 14:30 |  
| 2017-01-08 00:00 | 2017-01-08 00:00 |  
| 2017-01-09 09:00 | 2017-01-09 17:30 |  
+------------------+------------------+
```

Input time : 2017-01-02 16:52
adding minutes: 300
required time : 2017-01-03 12:22

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: where is the table?

Comment: edit the question and add the table, use control-k to format as code. or add 4 spaces

Answer (score 0):

If I understand clearly, you want:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR((540 + t.time)/60),'h ', MOD(540 + t.time, 60),'m') as HOURS 
FROM table t;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but it shows 42h 37m where as I need end date&time by adding number of minutes in start time based on business working hours.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DATE_ADD` is what you want

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(starttime, INTERVAL 300 MINUTE) as endtime;
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, I think i understand you know. The code below could probably be condensed, however, I left it verbose for readability.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
    DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(starttime), INTERVAL 300 MINUTE) 
    BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(DATE(starttime),'09:00') 
    AND TIMESTAMP(DATE(starttime),'17:30')
  THEN
    ## starttime plus 5 hours, is still in range of current business window
    DATE_ADD(starttime, INTERVAL 300 MINUTE)
  WHEN TIMESTAMP(starttime) > TIMESTAMP(DATE(starttime),'17:30') THEN
    ## startime falls after business hours, add it to the following day at 09:00 
    DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(DATE(starttime),'09:00'),
      INTERVAL (1440 /*24 hours (i.e. next day)*/ + 300 ) MINUTE
    )
  ELSE
    ## if the starttime falls within business hours, but extends into the next business day,
    ## calculate the difference up to 17:30, add to the following day, after 09:00 
    DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(DATE(starttime),'09:00'),
      INTERVAL (
        1440 + /*24 hours (i.e. next day)*/
        300  - /* standard working day */
        ABS(
          TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TIMESTAMP(DATE(starttime),'17:30'), starttime)
        ) /* less yesterday's minutes */
      ) MINUTE
    )
END AS endtime
;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but my daily working hours ends at 17:30. So clock should stop at 17:30 and start time calculation from next day.

Comment: @ShahidDada take a look at my update, this is most likely what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I go with the above input input time and number of minutes to be added, its working fine but when I change my input, it shows wrong result. Please see my changed input date and number of minutes to be added.

Input time : 2017-01-06 16:52  
adding minutes: 600  
output time : 2017-01-09 12:52